# Load single column from csv file

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `csv` file that contains large number of columns. I want to load just one column from that file using `spark`.

I know that we can use select statement to filter a column. But what i want, while doing the `read` operation itself, it should load just one column.

In this way, i should be able to avoid extra memory getting used by other columns. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Use parquet instead of csv.

Comment: as @Jay mentioned you need to use ***paraquet/orc*** or some similar file formats where they can provide file metadata and searchable organization of data. otherwise spark will load the complete record in-memory, apply schema and can pick that particular column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark will load complete file and parse for columns. As you mentioned, you can use select to restrict columns in dataframe, so dataframe will have only one column.

Answer (score 0):

Spark will load the complete file in memory and will filter down the column you want with the help of select statements which you have mentioned.

Because all the read operation in spark,  reads and scans the whole file as a distributed stream reader gets created (the reader gets instantiated at every node where the data has been stored).

And if your problem is to read the data column-wise then you can store the file in parquet format and read that file. Indeed, parquet is columnar storage and it is exactly meant for this type of use case(you can verify it using the explain).